# Difference between checkstyle-5.5.jar and checkstyle-5.5-all.jar?

Tags: checkstyle

I recently downloaded the [checkstyle 5.5 distribution](http://sourceforge.net/projects/checkstyle/files/checkstyle/5.5/). It contains two JAR files, *checkstyle-5.5.jar* and *checkstyle-5.5**-all**.jar*.

What is the difference between the two JARs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`checkstyle-5.5.jar` has dependencies on several other `.jar` files, like `antlr-2.7.7.jar`, `commons-cli-1.2.jar`, `google-collections-1.0.jar`, `commons-beanutils-core-1.8.3.jar`, etc.

Checkstyle and all its dependencies are bundled together in `checkstyle-5.5-all.jar`.